# C++11 placeholders with boost

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

This code ...

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    ClassA a;
    ClassB b, b2;
    a.SigA.connect( std::bind(&ClassB::PrintFoo, &b) );
    a.SigB.connect( std::bind(&ClassB::PrintInt, b,  _1));
    a.SigB.connect( std::bind(&ClassB::PrintInt, &b2, _1));

    a.SigA();
    a.SigB(4);
}
```

Gives the compilation error, "error: reference to '_1' is ambiguous"

It can be fixed by fully qualifying the placeholders ...

```
int main()
{
    // using namespace std::placeholders;
    ClassA a;
    ClassB b, b2;
    a.SigA.connect( std::bind(&ClassB::PrintFoo, &b) );
    a.SigB.connect( std::bind(&ClassB::PrintInt, b,  std::placeholders::_1));
    a.SigB.connect( std::bind(&ClassB::PrintInt, &b2, std::placeholders::_1));

    a.SigA();
    a.SigB(4);
}
```

...but why doesn't the first code snippet work?

**EDIT**

Just to prevent any ambiguity, I am compiling with Clang and Boost 1.52 with `--stdlib=libc++ -std=c++0x` and the entire code block is this ...

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct ClassA
{
    boost::signals2::signal<void ()>    SigA;
    boost::signals2::signal<void (int)> SigB;
};

struct ClassB
{
    void PrintFoo()      { std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl; }
    void PrintInt(int i) { std::cout << "Bar: " << i << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    // using namespace std::placeholders;
    ClassA a;
    ClassB b, b2;
    a.SigA.connect( std::bind(&ClassB::PrintFoo, &b) );
    a.SigB.connect( std::bind(&ClassB::PrintInt, b,  std::placeholders::_1));
    a.SigB.connect( std::bind(&ClassB::PrintInt, &b2, std::placeholders::_1));

    a.SigA();
    a.SigB(4);
}
```

Comment: What... compiler are you using? Edit: never mind, `clang` uses `__1` as its weird namespace thing.

Comment: If there is something else called _1 in scope, then you will get this error. [EDIT] a little too late!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Let's see how the includes work:

`#include <boost/signals2.hpp>` includes `#include <boost/signals2/signal.hpp>`
which includes `#include <boost/signals2/slot.hpp>` which includes `#include <boost/bind.hpp>` which includes `#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>` which includes `include <boost/bind/placeholders.hpp>`, which uses `static boost::arg<1> _1;`* in the global namespace, hence the ambiguity.

*: Technically, `_1` is in an unnamed namespace, but it visible due to a using directive.

One workaround is define the following at the top of your file so that `<boost/bind/placeholders.hpp>` is not included:

```
#define BOOST_BIND_NO_PLACEHOLDERS
```

Comment: Of all the great answers, this one most directly answers the question, so +1/Accept

Comment: I'm curious to know why Boost pollutes the global namespace this way? Why not let users do using namespace boost::placeholders; wherever they want to instead?

Answer (score 15):

C++ sees two global identifiers named `_1`. It has no idea that you mean `std::placeholders::_1` instead of Boost's `_1`. This is one of the reasons why the standard library puts them in a nested namespace: to prevent accidental conflicts like this.

If you need them to be shorter, just create a simple namespace alias:

```
namespace ph = std::placeholders
```

Then it's just `ph::_1`.

Answer (score 4):

GCC give the following information regarding your error:

```
.../include/c++/4.7.0/functional:864:34: \
    error: candidates are: const std::_Placeholder<1> std::placeholders::_1
.../boost/1.49.0/boost/bind/placeholders.hpp:55:15: \
    error:                 boost::arg<1> {anonymous}::_1
```

The hint to the problem can be found in the 2nd error: `boost::arg<1> {anonymous}::_1`

The cause is that the boost placeholders are in an anonymous namespace within the global namespace.

```
namespace
{
    boost::arg<1> _1;
    // etc...
} // unnamed namespace
```

Since the boost placeholders are in an anonymous namespace and you're importing `std::placeholders` into the global namespace, they are now both available in the global scope.

As such there is no way for the compiler to know which symbol you are referring to.

As Nicol suggests, use a *namespace alias* to create a shorthand prefix to `std::placeholders::_1` to reduce the typing.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `std::bind` I suppose you have some C++11 support. Consider also this version (i.e. prefer lambdas over `std::bind`)

```
int main()
{
    ClassA a;
    ClassB b, b2;
    a.SigA.connect( [&](){ b.PrintFoo(); } );
    a.SigB.connect( [&](int i){ b.PrintInt(i); } );
    a.SigB.connect( [&](int i){ b2.PrintInt(i); } );

    a.SigA();
    a.SigB(4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround to this within a scope by using a local variable:

```
{
    auto& _1 = std::placeholders::_1;
    auto f = std::bind(&Foo::bar, b, _1);
    ...
}
```