# What is wrong with this boost::signals2 implementation, using parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, signals

I am implementing a Dispatcher class using boost::signals2::signal. So far I've had success using signals without parameters, but I'm hitting a wall trying to implement them with parameters.

The Dispatcher looks like this:

```
#include "boost/signals2.hpp"

using namespace boost::signals2;

class Dispatcher {
public:
   signal<void ()> signal1;
   signal<void (int)> signal2;
};
```

There is a Controller class that will have functions bound to signals dispatched from the Dispatcher:

```
class Controller {
public:
    void onSignal1() {
        cout << "onSignal1()" << endl;
    }

    void onSignal2(int n) {
        count << "onSignal2()" << n << endl;
    }
};
```

In the main class Dispatcher signals are bound to Controller functions:

```
Dispatcher dispatcher;
Controller controller;

dispatcher.signal1.connect(boost::bind(&atlas::Controller::onSignal1, & controller));
dispatcher.signal1();

dispatcher.signal2.connect(boost::bind(&atlas::Controller::onSignal2, & controller, std::_1));
dispatcher.signal2(42);
```

This will not compile. Here is the error:
/boost/boost/bind/bind.hpp:313:9: No matching function for call to object of type 'boost::_mfi::mf1'

If the last two lines of the main file are commented out, everything works as expected. It is only when I attempt to connect the second signal to the function `onSignal2` that things break.

Comment: Boost bind and std placeholders? Are they compatible?

Comment: [Works fine with boost placeholders](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4c17249ad762677)

Comment: I think that there must be some incompatibility between the platform or OS and the version of boost that I'm using. I copied the script from the example you created and it is still failing with the exact same error.

Comment: Don't mix `boost::bind` and `std` placeholders

Comment: @IgorR. Can you provide a reason for that? Many of the examples I've seen do exactly that. Also, what is the alternative?

Comment: Could you provide a link to these examples? The reason is the fact `Boost.Bind` doesn't recognize std::_1 as a placeholder (see `Boost.Bind` sources). You can try and define the trait `boost::is_placeholder` for std placeholders, but why wouldn't you just use the Boost ones? They are in the global namespace: _1, _2 etc.

Comment: Here is one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596697/c11-placeholders-with-boost. When I just use _1 another error is thrown: Reference to '_1' is ambiguous.

Comment: The answers to this question clarify things quite a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596697/c11-placeholders-with-boost

Comment: In the example, they do *not* include `Boost.Bind` headers, but import `std::placeholders` namespace. Note that Boost placeholders "spoil" the global namespace, so you can't be `using std::placeholders`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this:

```
dispatcher.signal2.connect(boost::bind(&atlas::Controller::onSignal2, & controller, _1));
```

Instead of this:

```
dispatcher.signal2.connect(boost::bind(&atlas::Controller::onSignal2, & controller, std::_1));
```

**Rationale**

You have to use boost placeholders instead of std placeholders (since you are using boost::bind and not std::bind)
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/bind/placeholders.hpp
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders