# ‘boost::placeholders’ has not been declared : boost::placeholders::_1

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, ros

I am trying to launch a ROS project but I receive a very strange error: `‘boost::placeholders’ has not been declared`.

I have the following settings:

1. `Ubuntu 20.04`
2. ROS `Noetic`
3. `Boost 1.71`
4. `CMake` -> `cmake version 3.16.3`

Below a sample of the error I receive in the terminal:

```
In file included from /opt/ros/noetic/include/ros/node_handle.h:34,
                 from /opt/ros/noetic/include/ros/ros.h:45,
/opt/ros/noetic/include/ros/publisher.h: In member function ‘boost::function<void(const boost::shared_ptr<ros::SubscriberLink>&)> ros::Publisher::getLastMessageCallback()’:
/opt/ros/noetic/include/ros/publisher.h:179:70: error: ‘boost::placeholders’ has not been declared
  179 |       return boost::bind(&Impl::pushLastMessage, impl_.get(), boost::placeholders::_1);
```

Below the file that seems to carry this error is reported:

```
  template<class M, class T>
  Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, void(T::*fp)(M), T* obj,
                       const TransportHints& transport_hints = TransportHints())
  {
    SubscribeOptions ops;
    ops.template initByFullCallbackType<M>(topic, queue_size, boost::bind(fp, obj, boost::placeholders::_1));
    ops.transport_hints = transport_hints;
    return subscribe(ops);
  }
```

Following [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62737525/how-to-fix-error-1-was-not-declared-in-this-scope) I can confirm I added `C++14`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(lidar_boat_detection)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
add_compile_options(-std=c++14 -g)

find_package(PCL 1.8 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS 
  system
  filesystem 
  date_time 
  thread
 )


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS 
  roscpp
  pcl_conversions
  pcl_ros
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)
```

Also I consulted [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596697/c11-placeholders-with-boost/13597226) and I added `#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>` instead of `#include <boost/bind.hpp>` as per new directive and I added `using namespace boost::placeholders;`. However non of these solutions worked and another thing I tried was to add `#include <boost/bind/placeholders.hpp>` and that also didn't work:

```
#ifndef ROSCPP_PUBLISHER_HANDLE_H
#define ROSCPP_PUBLISHER_HANDLE_H

#include "ros/forwards.h"
#include "ros/common.h"
#include "ros/message.h"
#include "ros/serialization.h"

//#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>

#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>

using namespace boost::placeholders;

namespace ros
{

  class NodeHandleBackingCollection;

  ....

}
```

Always from the [same post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596697/c11-placeholders-with-boost/13597226) I tried to add the following line `#define BOOST_BIND_NO_PLACEHOLDERS` at the beginning of the file but that also didn't work:

```
#ifndef ROSCPP_PUBLISHER_HANDLE_H
#define ROSCPP_PUBLISHER_HANDLE_H

#define BOOST_BIND_NO_PLACEHOLDERS


#include "ros/forwards.h"
#include "ros/common.h"
#include "ros/message.h"
#include "ros/serialization.h"

//#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>

#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>

using namespace boost::placeholders;

namespace ros
{

  class NodeHandleBackingCollection;

  ....

}
```

I dug more and come across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62737525/how-to-fix-error-1-was-not-declared-in-this-scope) but unfortunately it was not useful to solve the problem.

[This question](https://answers.ros.org/question/372236/boostplaceholders-has-not-been-declared-ubuntu-2004ros-noetic/) would have been useful is a proper answer would have been provided as this is extremely close to the problem I have.

**EDITS**

```
Creating Package: template_package_msgs
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake:117 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "boost_bind"
  (requested version 1.71.0) with any of the following names:

    boost_bindConfig.cmake
    boost_bind-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "boost_bind" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "boost_bind_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "boost_bind" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake:182 (boost_find_component)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:443 (find_package)
  template_package/template_package_msgs/CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/emanuele/sonar_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/emanuele/sonar_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log"
```

I am running out of ideas on how to solve it. Thanks for pointing in the right direction for solving this issue.

Comment: I do not think that making changes to the ROS library code is a good idea but could you revert the code to its initial form and then **replace `boost::placeholders::_1` with `_1`**. What you could try as well is again reverting your changes and add **[`add_definitions(-DBOOST_BIND_NO_PLACEHOLDERS)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html) to your `CMakeLists.txt` file** instead of adding it to the ROS header itself. This way you can make sure it is definitely respected before any other Boost headers are included.

Comment: `#include <boost/bind.hpp` should be correct for Boost 1.71. It handles pre-processor definitions such as `BOOST_BIND_NO_PLACEHOLDERS`. You can check if that is the case by opening `usr/include/boost` and check if `bind.hpp` is there and what the contents of the file are.

Comment: I agree 101% with you not modifying the ROS library code! However I am at the last resort because I tried everything I can possibly think ok. For example yesterday I uninstalled/re-installed ROS three times, uninstalled every instance of `boost` and today I re-installed ROS `Noetic` only (as it comes with the proper version of `boost 1.71`) I checked this with `dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'` right after installing `Noetic`; to double check I also did `ldconfig -p | grep libboost)`

Comment: To make sure I erased any instance of `boost` before installing `Noetic` I even did `sudo apt autopurge $(dpkg -l | grep boost | grep 1.71 | awk '{print $2}')`. Finally I tried your suggestion to `add_definitions(-DBOOST_BIND_NO_PLACEHOLDERS)` to all the proper `CMakeLists.txt` file but nothing changed.

Comment: I went and checked `usr/include/boost` and can confirm that `bind.hpp` is there. Last thing left to try for me is the hard way: replace `boost::placeholders::_1` with `_1`. I am not a big fan of that because modifying the ROS library code is not good. But I really have no idea what is wrong...

Comment: Yes, indeed weird thing. I could only try it out on a Ubuntu 20.04 machine on Tuesday. But if you make a minimal reproducible example and push it onto Git, I'd give it a go then. But certainly try `_1` with and without `BOOST_BIND_NO_PLACEHOLDERS` first. I can remember I had a similar issue with non-ROS code at some point.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that first and if nothing happens I will write a small ros node to push on Git as a minimal reproducible example. I will let you know a little later.

Comment: Sure. I have an idea what could be happening but I can't promise anything. Thank you!

Comment: Hello ok, after other trials it still not working. I created a minimal verifiable example you can clone from [here](https://bitbucket.org/ERaggi/sonar_messages/src/master/). Unfortunately I still get the same error. In order to make it as basic as possible I took the example from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29)

Comment: Also [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/41ihl0hdktvzkkb/catkin_error.17?dl=0) I made a quick 1 min video where you can see the error real-time. I am using Qt5 as editor.

Comment: Sadly couldn't replicate it on my Ubuntu 20.04 system. If you ask me the code itself is perfectly valid. There must be an issue with the compilation somehow. The last thing that comes to my mind is to try adding `find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS bind)` to the `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for your time! Actually after putting `find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS bind)` I received an interesting error. I added **EDITS** on the question. Does that tell you anything?

Comment: Also, the code I posted on Bitbucket, you were able to compile it correctly?

Comment: I tried it and for me it works without the added definition. Furthermore I just found out the `find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS bind)` indeed does not work as [`bind` is not built separately](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries) like e.g. `filesystem` and `date_time` are but is header only. Sorry, for suggesting it before trying it myself! Have a look at the answer I gave you and let me know if it works.

Comment: Did my solution work for you or did you resolve it in any other way?

Comment: I have two machines with the same setup above, one of them showing this same error while the other is not! really confusing, reinstalling boost or ROS didn't solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

There was a recent improvement to Boost Bind, see [Why boost::bind insists pulling `boost::placeholders` into global namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203970/why-boostbind-insists-pulling-boostplaceholders-into-global-namespace/65813178#65813178)

It looks like you want to define `BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS` unless you want to update the calling code. Check that `BOOST_BIND_NO_PLACEHOLDERS` is *not defined*

Answer (score 0):

I have trouble replicating your exact problem on my system. If I clone your minimal example from your Bitbucket but leave the line **`add_definitions(-DBOOST_BIND_NO_PLACEHOLDERS)`** in the `CMakeLists.txt` then it gives me the same error you got but if I **remove** it I do not have these issues and it compiles fine. If this error persists on your system even though you remove this line, the only plausible reason that I can come up with is that for some obscure reason **some other package in your workspace or ROS itself adds this definition** which makes the compilation of your package then fail. I would actually try to make a new workspace (or put `CATKIN_IGNORE` files into the other packages in your workspace and then `$ catkin clean` the workspace followed by `$ catkin build`) and see if it still occurs with your Bitbucket code as the only package in your workspace. If it compiles keep adding the packages until you find out which of your other packages might be causing it. If it does not then the only way of solving this dilemma that comes to my mind is adding the line

```
#undef BOOST_BIND_NO_PLACEHOLDERS
```

to the top of your two `.cpp` files `talker.cpp` and `subscriber.cpp` (before actually including `ros/ros.h`). This might though lead to problems when combining it with code that relies on `BOOST_BIND_NO_PLACEHOLDERS`. In order to reduce the chances of it breaking your code do not add it to header files as then it might leak into code including your header file.